# Java 'cannot find symbol' for Scanner object

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LSArrayApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(ReadFile());

    }


    public static String[] ReadFile(){

        try{
            File myFile =new File("fileName.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
            System.out.println("Scanner creation succesful");
            }


        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
            }


        String[] data =  new String[2976];        
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            data[lineNumber] = scan.nextLine();
            lineNumber++;

        return data;
        }
```

Everytime I run the code I get this error:

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable scan
  location: class LSArrayApp

It seems that the scanner object is not instantiating and I can't figure out why.

Comment: `scan` is defined with the context of the `try-catch` block, it is not accessible out side of it, in fact, you shouldn't trust it as you wouldn't know if it was successful initialised or not without doing a `null` check first. Ok, having said all that.  Move the rest of the code instead the `try-catch` block, or better, remove the `try-catch` and simply allow the exception to be thrown from the method so that the caller becomes responsible for dealing with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not compile, so it cannot be true that you run the program.

The variable "scan" is unknown outside the try block. You need to declare it  before `try`.

```
Scanner scan;
try
{
    File myFile =new File("fileName.txt");
    scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    System.out.println("Scanner creation succesful");
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("File not found");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

2) Arrays have a fixed size. To read a file with unknown size you may use the `ArrayList` class instead.

3) After the exception you should exit the program, otherwise the code below will fail because the scanner is not initialized.

Comment: What would be the best way to define scan outside the try-catch block?

Comment: I added an example above

Comment: ((Obs: since [JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) we can kind of run a program without explicit compiling it - but doubt that is the case here))